# Problem with a model and DataAttribute [Required] used even if not present on property

Tags: c#, system.reflection

I have this model :

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Core.Domain.Models.Contracts.V1._0
{
    public class Body
    {
        [StringLength(10)]
        public string field1 { get; set; }

        [StringLength(20)]
        public string field2 { get; set; }

        public string field3 { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(3, MinimumLength = 3)]
        public string field4 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

So far so good, problem is when I check model throughout reflection, all fields are flagued as required even if not in the model.
Here result of the analasys :

```
    Field: <field1>, Attribut de données: System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.StringLengthAttribute
    Field: <field1>, Attribut de données: System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RequiredAttribute

    Field: <field2>, Attribut de données: System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.StringLengthAttribute
    Field: <field2>, Attribut de données: System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RequiredAttribute

    Field: <field3>, Attribut de données: System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.StringLengthAttribute
    Field: <field3>, Attribut de données: System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RequiredAttribute

    Field: <field4>, Attribut de données: System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RequiredAttribute
    Field: <field4>, Attribut de données: System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.StringLengthAttribute
```

and of course, if I try to validate model but not passing field1 or field2, I came out with a validation error

Of course, question is why?

Comment: Should it be [Required()]?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute?view=net-7.0

Comment: No it shouldn't, else everyting would work as expected.

In fact I will need a kind of [NotRequired] data annotation as it seems Required appeared by default even if not set.

FYI I removed the [StringLength(xx)] data annotation and the result is the same